# Is it advisable to delete ~/.cache files?

Tags: files, cache

```
~/.cache/*
```

Is it good to delete all the files in `.cache` folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cache folder is a place programs stored data they may need again, it is kept for speed but is not essential to keep. It can be generated again or downloaded again (depending on the data and the program).

If your hard drive is really filling up it may be worth checking the `.cache` folder but it is unlikely to be too huge. If it gets too big you can delete things without worrying. But probably if a GB or 2 is having a significant effect on your performance you may need to consider moving other files or getting more storage.

Answer (score 3):

As you can deduct from its name, it's a cache. Deleting its content doesn't harm your system.

I've removed my cache folder many times without any problems.

At the latest after a new login, everything is back to normal.

But you will notice an increased activity of your system because the cache of the various programs will be recreated.